# Add data in specific rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

After I click the command button, I want my excel to do:

- Input what I type in text boxes / select in combo boxes in specific columns without deleting the one I previously entered

But at this moment, it does not work as I expected or enter any of input from text boxes and combo boxes.

The script I wrote is:

```
Private Sub
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Or TextBox3.Value = "" Then
        If MsgBox ("There might one or more empty cells, 
        do you want to continue to proceed?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Dim invsheet As Worksheet
Dim pacsheet As Worksheet

Set invsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INV")
Set pacsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAC")

invsheet.Range("A1").Value = TextBox6.Text
invsheet.Range("I5").Value = TextBox7.Text
invsheet.Range("A21").Value = TextBox5.Text
invsheet.Range("A25").Value = ComboBox1.Value

inv_nr = invsheet.Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1
invsheet.Cells(inv_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox1
invsheet.Cells(inv_nr, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox2

pac_nr = pacsheet.Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox2
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox3
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4
```

Problem:

```
inv_nr = invsheet.Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1
invsheet.Cells(inv_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox1
invsheet.Cells(inv_nr, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox2

pac_nr = pacsheet.Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox2
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 7).Value = Me.TextBox3      'mistyped it. supposed to be 7
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 9).Value = Me.TextBox4      'mistyped it. supposed to be 9
```

This block of code does not work and create any output on the worksheet.

I will really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not placing anything in column A (except A1, A21, and A25 of `invsheet`), so it's not a good idea to set your `inv_nr` and `pac_nr` variables based on the last used cell in column A.

Try basing it on one of the columns you are populating with data, e.g. column 5:

```
'Always qualify "Rows" (and don't mistype it as "Row")
inv_nr = invsheet.Cells(invsheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
invsheet.Cells(inv_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox1
invsheet.Cells(inv_nr, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox2

'Always qualify "Rows" (and don't mistype it as "Row")
pac_nr = pacsheet.Cells(pacsheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox2 'Note: This is pointless because the next line overwrites it
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox3 'Note: This is pointless because the next line overwrites it
pacsheet.Cells(pac_nr, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4
```

Comment: Hello, yowE3K. I appreciate your advice. I actually mistyped those with Textbox2,3 and 4.

Comment: @HyundoJang - If you don't qualify the `Rows` (and `Range` and `Cells`) by specifying which sheet it is referring to, it defaults to referring to the `ActiveSheet`.  So `pac_nr = pacsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1` is equivalent to `pac_nr = pacsheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1`.  It's possible for the `ActiveSheet` to be in a new format Excel file and have a `Rows.Count` of 1048576, but `pacsheet` might be an old format worksheet which only has 65536 rows.  Trying to do `pacsheet.Cells(1048576, 5)` would then crash because that cell wouldn't exist.

Comment: Wow, after I saw your comment, I realized what I needed was the definition of each codes, such as .Cells(Rows.Count). I didn't really had a good understanding of it and that's why I could not figure out what the real problem is. Thanks for your help!